# Linux Kernel Platform Driver: Modifications to _probe() for multiple Devices

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, soc

What modifications must be done to a Linux kernel driver to support (equal) multiple devices(myipcore) on a SoC (defined in the device tree) instead of only one?

In my application: only one process will open the appropriate `/dev/myipcoreX` file!

*Device Tree:*

```
 amba: amba {
    compatible = "simple-bus";
    #address-cells = <2>;
    #size-cells = <2>;
    ranges;

    axi_myipcore1: myipcore@A0001000 {
        compatible = "xy,my-ip-core-1.00";
        status = "disabled";
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupts = <0 89 1>;
        reg = <0x0 0xA0001000 0x0 0x14>;
    };

    axi_myipcore2: myipcore@A0002000 {
        compatible = "xy,my-ip-core-1.00";
        status = "disabled";
        interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
        interrupts = <0 90 1>;
        reg = <0x0 0xA0002000 0x0 0x14>;
    };
    ....
 }
```

For each device tree entry the `_probe()` function of the driver is called. How to get dynamically the next minor number for `alloc_chrdev_region()` and how to execute `class_create()` only once?

Or do I have to modify the device tree?

You see, I'm looking for the central theme....

Comment: Part of the functions should be called from module `->init()` stage, where you allocate major. In `->probe()` you will call API to create a device which will allocate minor.

Comment: I use module_platform_driver() but not module_init(). As far as I know only one of both can be used, is this right? Could you give an example code?

Comment: Yes, in your case you need to switch back to `module_init()` / `module_exit()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. But one question is left: how to determine the number of myipcore-entries in the device tree when calling `alloc_chrdev_region()` in `module_init()`? Do I have to hard code it into the driver?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to specify an upper limit on the number of minor device numbers when you call `alloc_chrdev_region()`. But you do not necessarily need to know how many matching devices are in the device tree, you just need to make sure you reserve at least enough.